# MVC4 Razor Update View in Real time

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4, signalr, real-time

I'm a relative noob programmer so apologies in advance!

I am writing using MVC4 and Razor and have a user selection view that can potentially lead to many web calls being made from the controller. I want to update the result view 
in real-time as these web service calls return, at the minute though it seems that the controller waits until all the web calls are finished before updating the model 
and rendering the result view. We have attempted to use async and await to improve things with only marginal success.

Other complications I have are that we are using an in house framework and performing other operations once the webcall returns e.g. logging \ occasional db access, all of which 
lead to the controller action taking a substantial period.

To put it in context this is a monitoring application so depending on the user selections we may have 0 -> several hundred internal web service calls made on the click of a button.

So essentially I am wondering how this is best handled e.g. realtime updating of an MVC4 view where you have multiple individual web service calls, some of them potentially 
lengthy e.g. up to 60seconds max.

My thoughts on how to improve things were

1. use SignalR and at the point where the individual webservices respond, broadcast an update to the result screen ~ however I still have the issue that the code is waiting for 
   my controller call to the webservices to finish before rendering the view.
2. to avoid wait on controller method e.g. 'output = await pc.CallApproriateSCs(selectedServiceInfoDetails);' perhaps pass all the calls off to some internal stack and have a timer 
   pop them and process them on a different thread in another class, this could then free my controller to display a defaulted result view immediately, letting SignalR update it in
   real-time

it all seems a bit like using a sledgehammer to crack a walnut though, surely MVC4 has some nicer way of handling this scenario?

Thanks in advance,

N

```
public virtual async Task<ActionResult> MultipleCommand(ManualSelectionVM model)
{
    var viewObject = new ManualSelectionResultVM();            

    if (model != null)
    {

        var input = new ServiceInfo();
        //Retrieving serviceInfo object details from cache based on user selection, they are unique     
        List<ServiceInfo> selectedServiceInfoDetails = GetServiceInfoDetailsFromCache(GetSelectedServiceInfoIDs(model));
        List<ServiceOutputCdt> output = new List<ServiceOutputCdt>();                        
        IGenericPC pc = null;

        try
        {
            pc = PCFactory.Create<IGenericPC>();
            output = await pc.CallApproriateSCs(selectedServiceInfoDetails);
            viewObject = ConvertServiceOutputIntoVM(output);
        }
        finally
        {
            AICS.ARCHITECTURE.SERVICES.CLEANUP.CleanupSVC.Cleanup(pc);
        }
    }                

    return this.View(MVC.ManualSelection.Views.Result, viewObject);
}
```